# GitHub desktop - how can i add a project to a repository or branch?

Tags: github, github-desktop

How can i add files to a repository or a branch?

I have onje branch where i want to add files, but when i create new repository,it creates on another github host and not on that branch. How can i add files on that branch?

Answer (score 0):

Move the files in the project directory after choosing the desired branch. Commit and push the new files.